# Functions NameError

Tags: python, nameerror, function

I have been messing around with some code, trying to create a function for work planning. However I am stuck and wondered if someone could help? Thanks

```
class Work_plan(object):
    def __init__(self,hours_work,work_len, work_des):
        self.hours_work = hours_work
        self.work_len = work_len
        self.work_des = work_des

        work_load = []
        hours_worked = []
        if hours_worked > hours_work:
            print "Too much work!"
        else:
            work_load.append(work_des)
            hours_worked.append(work_len)
            print "The work has been added to your work planning!"

work_request = Work_plan(8, 2, "task1")
Work_plan
print work_load
```

it comes up with the error:
       NameError: name 'work_load' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the variable `work_load` inside the `__init__` of the class, so you can't access it outside this scope.

If you want to have access to `work_load`, make it an attribute for objects of `Work_plan` class, and the access it by doing `object.work_plan`

For example:

```
class Work_plan(object):
    def __init__(self,hours_work,work_len, work_des):
        self.hours_work = hours_work
        self.work_len = work_len
        self.work_des = work_des

        self.work_load = []
        self.hours_worked = []
        if hours_worked > hours_work:
            print "Too much work!"
        else:
            self.work_load.append(work_des)
            self.hours_worked.append(work_len)
            print "The work has been added to your work planning!"

work_request = Work_plan(8, 2, "task1")
Work_plan
print work_request.work_load
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! When I use your code, it comes up with:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "w.p_suggested_answer.py", line 16, in <module>
    work_request = Work_plan(8, 2, "task1")
  File "w.p_suggested_answer.py", line 9, in __init__
    if hours_worked > hours_work:
NameError: global name 'hours_worked' is not defined

Comment: @Mrv use `self.hours_work` instead of `hours_work` every time, and `self.hours_worked` instead of `self.hours_worked`

Comment: Thank you! I would have given up without your help.

Comment: @Mrv Do not forget to accept the answer as best answer if it helped you :) ! Cheers